# DataBinding Linq to SQL table to DataGrid using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, datagrid

:) Hi guys! I am trying to show only two columns from my tblEmployeeLoginDetails Table and not show every single one of the 13 that is available, but the columns that I added manually stay empty when I have already bind them to my datagrid. Here is my coding for my XAMl:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgEmployeeInformation" ItemsSource="{Binding tblEmployeeLoginDetails}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,391,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="175" Width="241" SelectionChanged="dgEmployeeInformation_SelectionChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeName}" Header="First Name" MinWidth="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeSurname}" Header="Last Name"  MinWidth="120"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is my coding where I bind everything:

```
    private void FillEmployeeDataGrid()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            dgEmployeeInformation.ItemsSource = DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails.Where<tblEmployeeLoginDetail>(c => c.LoginID != null)
                .Select<tblEmployeeLoginDetail, EIDData>(m => new EIDData()
                {
                    LoginIdentification = m.LoginID,
                    Name = m.EmployeeName,
                    Surname = m.EmployeeSurname,
                    Email = m.EmployeeEmailAddress,
                    Password = m.EmployeePassword,
                    Department = m.EmployeeDepartment,
                    IDNumber = m.EmployeeIDNumber,
                    Gender = m.EmployeeGender,
                    HomeAddress = m.EmployeeHomeAddress,
                    Telephone = m.EmployeeTelephoneNumber,
                    City = m.EmplyeeCity,
                    Province = m.EmployeeProvinceCode
                });
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why my table information is not showing data in my DataGrid?

Comment: post the part where you bind data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it was pretty easy, but you have mistyped the name of the properties as you seen from this code:

```
Name = m.EmployeeName,
Surname = m.EmployeeSurname,
```

So, just change your `.xaml` as:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="First Name" MinWidth="120"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Surname}" Header="Last Name"  MinWidth="120"/>
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you very much man for showing my simple mistake! ;) This worked.